# Error when OleDB(ACE) Read the .xls file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, xls, oledbconnection

```
    string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";


        OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(@connStr);
        MyConnection.Open(); // Here the error come...
```

Im try to using this connStr to connect to My xls file. The problem was "External table is not in the expected format."

Im have aleady installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64. But the error still remain.

How to connect to this .xls file ?

Comment: Are you sure this is not an xlsx or xlsb file?  Can you show the contents of the `path` variable?

Comment: Yes the file type was .xls file and detail are Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls) @Hambone

Comment: Then this should work -- your syntax looks correct.  My only thought is you mentioned you installed the 64-bit engine.  Have you tried the 32-bit?

Comment: I have try all of these two. But the same error still remain @Hambone

Comment: This is not an answer by any stretch, but to aid in debugging, create a very simple xls file with a few columns and consistent data, for example a 4 x 4 with all numbers.  Run this same code for that file.  If it bombs, then it has to be a setup issue.  If it doesn't bomb, then the error has to be with the file you are trying to read.  This will at least narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: I have 3 files. All are xls. I used this ConnectionString and there were 2 files can connect. The last one has bombs. I'm use this code in other 32 bits pc to run and it can read the problem files. @Hambone

Comment: Okay, that helps.  My only remaining thought and thing to test.  Thought: maybe there are some datatyping issues, where OLE thinks a field is numeric and then it sees text.  That actually doesn't make sense because your error is on the `Connection.Open()` method, but you never know.  Thing to test:  Copy paste the worksheet in question to a clean sheet and see if OleReader can connect to it -- maybe it has something to do with the file being corrupt, but not corrupt enough for Excel.  Lastly, maybe just to check, save as XLSX and see if that works?

Comment: I got the answer. My file wasn't a xls file. But it type are xls. When i open it with Microsift Excel, their a dialog told that the file format didn't match. I should go check the file. Thank you very much. @Hambone